DynamoDbIndex.scan() with filter expression doesn't work
In my code I use this class as Java entity for DynamoDB table:
@DynamoDbBean
@Data
public class RecordDynamoDB {
    private String id;
    private String customerIdHash;
    private OffsetDateTime expirationTime;

    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @DynamoDbSecondarySortKey(indexNames = {"expirationTime-index"})
    @DynamoDbConvertedBy(DynamoDBTimestampConverter.class)
    public OffsetDateTime getExpirationTime() {
        return expirationTime;
    }

    @DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey(indexNames = "customerIdHash-index")
    public String getCustomerIdHash() {
        return customerIdHash;
    }
}

This code allows we to look for the items with desired status and expiration time:
var attributeValueMap = Map.of(
        ":status", AttributeValue.fromS(Status.EXPIRED.getValue()),
        ":expirationTime", DATE_TIME_CONVERTER.transformFrom(now)
);

var scanRequest = ScanRequest.builder()
        .tableName(TABLE_NAME)
        .filterExpression("expirationTime < :expirationTime AND grant.#status = :status")
        .expressionAttributeValues(attributeValueMap)
        .expressionAttributeNames(Map.of("#status", "status"))
        .build();

return dynamoDbClient.scan(scanRequest)
        .items()
        .stream()
        .map(recordTableSchema::mapToItem)
        .toList();

The code above works as expected.
Now I want to use index in order to load the data faster. I create GSI called expirationTime-index with customerIdHash as partition key and expirationTime as sort key. Then I rewrite my code:
var attributeValueMap = Map.of(
        ":status", AttributeValue.fromS(ConsentGrantStatus.EXPIRED.getValue()),
        ":expirationTime", DATE_TIME_CONVERTER.transformFrom(now)
);

DynamoDbIndex<ConsentRecordDynamoDB> index = table(TABLE_NAME, ConsentRecordDynamoDB.class).index(INDEX_NAME);

var expression = Expression.builder()
        .expression("expirationTime < :expirationTime AND grant.#status = :status")
        .expressionNames(Map.of("#status", "status"))
        .expressionValues(attributeValueMap)
        .build();

return index.scan(builder -> builder.filterExpression(expression))
        .stream()
        .map(Page::items)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .toList();

This code employing index.scan() doesn't return any record. What am I doing wrong here?
UPD1 I've updated getCustomerIdHash() to point out it's used in expirationTime-index but still no luck
@DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey(indexNames = {"customerIdHash-index", "expirationTime-index"})
public String getCustomerIdHash() {
    return this.customerIdHash;
}

UPD2 index.scan().stream().toList() returns me an empty page (table itself has 48 records).

From what you shared you haven't defined your index correctly:
    @DynamoDbSecondarySortKey(indexNames = {"expirationTime-index"})
    @DynamoDbConvertedBy(DynamoDBTimestampConverter.class)
    public OffsetDateTime getExpirationTime() {
        return expirationTime;
    }

    @DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey(indexNames = "customerIdHash-index")
    public String getCustomerIdHash() {
        return customerIdHash;
    }

Notice how expirationTime-index only has a sort key, no partition key. Check the web console to understand if you have data on that index, and if the index actually exists.

Thanks, I've updated declaration of getCustomerIdHash() and looked into web console: index exists, but there are no items there (the table itself has 48 records).
